# Spring WebFlux. There are two ways to get data from database (direct and flux-operators)? What difference?

Tags: spring-data, reactive-programming

I use Spring Data and WebFlux.
I have two ways to get data from the database.

First way: 
I can get data using a request like -

```
Flux(?) findAllByName(String name)
```

Second way:
I can use operators since I use WebFlux

```
findAll().filter(x -> x.name.equals(name))
```

What is the difference?
Which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

For `Flux(?) findAllByName(String name)` filtering happens inside the database that returns only records with a matching name.

For `findAll().filter(x -> x.name.equals(name))` you get all the records from the database (table, document collection, ...) and filter them inside your application.

If your database stores gigabytes of data, moving it all around the network is not a viable strategy. Therefore the first variant is preferred.